# I want the text of 'td' but it's giving error Also, I don't the <a> tag (I want to delete it completely only I want the text containing in it)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want retrieve the names from the table and store them in a list. https://www.in.pampers.com/pregnancy/baby-names/article/top-indian-baby-names

However, I am not able to get the text. It returns 
 `'NoneType' object has not attribute 'text'`

https://www.in.pampers.com/pregnancy/baby-names/article/top-indian-baby-names

Also, I don't want the anchor tag to be included in the list of names. I just want the text of the anchor tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

web_page = requests.get("https://www.in.pampers.com/pregnancy/baby-names/article/top-indian-baby-names")

# if requests.status_code == 200:
bs = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, 'lxml')

tables = bs.findAll("table")

for table in tables:
  for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    print(row.find('td').text)
```

Comment: `it's giving error`: What is the error?

Comment: 'NoneType' object has not attribute 'text' Below code is giving the error

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://www.in.pampers.com/pregnancy/baby-names/article/top-indian-baby-names")

names = []
for item in df:
    names.extend(item['Name'].to_list())

print(names)
```

Output:

```
['Aaradhya', 'Adah', 'Adhira', 'Alisha', 'Amoli', 'Anaisha', 'Ananya', 'Anika', 'Anushka', 'Asmee', 'Avni', 'Carina', 'Drishti', 'Hiya', 'Ira', 'Ishana', 'Ishita', 'Kaia', 'Kashvi', 'Keya', 'Kimaya', 'Krisha', 'Larisa', 'Mahika', 'Mayra', 'Mehar', 'Mirai', 'Mishka', 'Naitee', 'Navya', 'Nehrika', 'Neysa', 'Pavati', 'Prisha', 'Ryka', 'Rebecca', 'Saanvi', 'Sahana', 'Sai', 'Saisha', 'Saloni', 'Shanaya', 'Shrishti', 'Sneha', 'Taahira', 'Taara', 'Tanvi', 'Viti', 'Zara', 'Aahva', 'Aadiv', 'Aarav', 'Akanksh', 'Alex', 'Anant', 'Atiksh', 'Ayaan', 'Bhuv', 'Dasya', 'Gian', 'Hem', 'Idhant', 'Ishank', 'Jash', 'Jay', 'Joseph', 'Kabir', 'Kahaan', 'Kairav', 'Kevin', 'Laksh', 'Luv', 'Manan', 'Mohammad', 'Naksh', 'Nimit', 'Nirav', 'Pahal', 'Parv', 'Pranay', 'Rachit', 'Raj', 'Ranbir', 'Raunak', 'Reyansh', 'Rishaan', 'Rishit', 'Rohan', 'Rudra', 
'Rushil', 'Sadhil', 'Sarthak', 'Taarush', 'Taksh', 'Ved', 'Vihaan', 'Vivaan', 'Yash', 'Yug', 'Zuber']
```

Comment: What does this do? Are they boy names or girl names (there are two tables on that page)?

Comment: @Selcuk have you read _I want the names from the table and store them in a list._ ? and _table.findAll("tr")_ ?

Comment: I don't want to use panda can you please do this in Beautifulsoup?